# Extra New Lines When Writing Java File on Linux vs Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, ubuntu, file-io

I have a .txt file that I am writing using Java which has a very specific arrangement of new lines. This arrangement is enforced when I write the file on Windows, but when I run the same code on Ubuntu, there are two new lines for every place where there should be one. Does anyone know what might be causing this? This is the code I am using to write:

```
List<String>toBeWrittenList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int x=0; x < finalList.size(); x++){
        toBeWrittenList.add("\n");
        toBeWrittenList.add("==level " + (x+1) +"==");
        for(int y=0; y < finalList.get(x).size();y++){
            if(finalList.get(x).get(y).equals("N"))
                toBeWrittenList.add(y+1 + ". null");
            else
                toBeWrittenList.add(y+1 + ". " + finalList.get(x).get(y));
        }
    }
    try {
        writeSmallTextFile(toBeWrittenList, FILE_NAME3);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

static void writeSmallTextFile(List<String> aLines, String aFileName) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        Files.write(path, aLines, ENCODING);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use PrintWriter method println to create a text file. The println will check your OS and choose the correct feed line (\n or \n\r).

The problem probably exist in Files.write. Are you write the class yourself? or are you using 3rd party library?

Comment: I believe Files.write is part of Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: PrintWriter seems to ignore newlines altogether.

Comment: sorry, i thought you are using java 6. Never have chance to use java 7. How do you use the PrintWriter? I usually write it like this: for (String line : aLines) pw.println(line). Where pw is PrintWriter object.

Answer (score -1):

Windows uses a "\r\n" pair of characters to distinguish newlines, while Linux treats "\n" as a newline, and seemingly "\r", too. Hence "\r\n" looks more like two newlines in Linux.

Run your text files through `dos2unix` when you copy them to a Linux box, to translate "\r\n" to "\n". Run your text files through `unix2dos` when you copy them back to Windows, to translate "\n" back to "\r\n" pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "copy" it to a Linux box - it is being generated by a .jar file. How would I incorporate your approach in that case?

Comment: Oh, well why didn't you say so in the first place? Can you please provide a SSCCE?

Comment: Very well. Since that is what you call *compilable*, please fix [the error messages that compiling your code produces](http://ideone.com/K8StE9).

Comment: It is not compilable. I wasn't sure what the term meant.